# Is it possible to send the message data when app is closed

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

When the app is closed, the message data can not be sent to the device any more. Is there any way to send the message to open the app directly.

Comment: ??? Which message data? To which device?

Comment: give some clear details about your problem so that we can help you quicly

Comment: Data message can be sent until pushToken is valid. Any message  can be received while app is not in "Force closed" state. May be this is your case?

Comment: I tried when the app is closed, the message can not be send to the android app, but the notification can show, but i do not need the notification just need the message payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for Huawei phones in Chinese Mainland, data messages can be send even the app is killed if the phone meets EMUI 10 or later version.
If the problem persists, could provide the log for us to check.

Comment: Is it possible to use data message to open app? So if the app is killed, it also can receive the data.

Comment: Is it possible to use data message to open app? --- yes